Windows 11 install via SCCM fails with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE on HP 860G10 laptops
We're trying to install Windows 11 on HP 860 G10 laptops via SCCM (PXE), but unfortunately are not able to do so. After the laptops reboot and start installing Windows 11, it takes a while (30 seconds) before they BSOD with an INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE message.
The same task sequence has always worked for Windows 10 installations, and does still work for Windows 11  on HP 860 G9 laptops.
I'm thinking there is a possible driver issue with regards to the NVMe, yet there are no drivers specifically for the NVMe available from HP, nor from Western Digital. Also, the entire SCCM driver package has been included as an Apply Drivers task in the task sequence, and all drivers are available in the prepared install.wim Windows image.
I've also had a look at the partition table that is being created by the task sequence: the partition table is exactly the same as for the G9 laptops, yet there is no partition marked as "boot". No idea why, though.
The fact that we're new to SCCM doesn't really help either...
Is there anybody who recognizes this error and is kind enough to share some insight?
Thanks!
Edit 1 - added BCDEDIT output for Greg Askew
Windows Boot Manager
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  nl-NL
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {96021b33-3dea-11ef-a8d4-c07355a8480a}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  nl-NL
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {96021b33-3dea-11ef-a8d4-c07355a8480a}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard


What does bcdedit show?

@Greg Askew - I've added the bcdedit output to my question as an edit.

Is this a simple installation, or the task sequence that creates a temporary partition for saving user data?

@Greg Askew - This is a basic installation. I've managed to get the task sequence up and running again, and I can install Windows 11 on my laptops once again. Thank you very much for your assistance!

I've managed to find out what went wrong during the installation via SCCM, so if anyone is ever faced with the same issue, here is what solved it for me.
After a lot of trial and error I decided to start again from scratch, by first removing all additional drivers from the task sequence. As soon as I tried to run the task sequence without drivers, the installation succeeded.
Prior to this, I had added the entire driver package for the HP 865 G10 laptops, and some additional drivers (for the USB-to-RJ45 dongle and some Intel drivers).
I had configured SCCM to find the best matching driver for each device, so it is my guess that the installation process found a driver that was a better match, yet didn't work as expected.
As soon as all (additional) drivers were removed from the task sequence, the Windows 11 installation worked again.
I'll be adding the HP drivers later on after Windows 11 is installed.
